# Passing / calling variables / functions in prolog

Tags: prolog

```
degmintoradians( degmin( Degrees, Minutes ), radians ) :-
    print('test2'),
    radians is ((Degrees + Minutes) / 60) * (pi / 180).



distance( Airport1, Airport2, DistanceMiles ) :-

    airport( Airport1, _, Latitude1, Longitude1 ),
    airport( Airport2, _, Latitude2, Longitude2 ),

    print('test1'),
    degmintoradians( Latitude1, latrads1 ),
    .....
```

What I'm trying to do is pretty simple, just pass "Latitude1" and "longitude1" into degmintoradians. The print cases are tests, when running the full code, "test1" is printed, however "test2" is not. I can't seem to figure out why, I think I'm doing everything right.

In case it helps, airports are stored in a database like this:

```
airport( atl, 'Atlanta         ', degmin(  33,39 ), degmin(  84,25 ) ).
```

Thanks.

Comment: `radians` should be `Radians` (first letter upper case) because you want them to be variables (otherwise they are atoms). The same goes for `latrads1`.

Comment: Well don't I look silly, thanks.